# Slack reminder for every three months

Tags: slack

I am trying to set a Slack reminder for every three months:

```
/remind #random "yada yada https://www.gebruikercentraal.nl/events.ics." every 3 months
```

but this doesn't work. This does work instead:

- every month
- every 2 weeks

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 27):

Would this work for your need?

```
/remind #random "test" every 12 weeks
```

Comment: Here's how to allow specifying the start date e.g. beginning of every quarter: `/remind me "do that" every 12 weeks starting September 1`

Comment: 4 weeks is not an exact match for 1 month. This only works if you don't mind the reminder date "slipping" over time.

Answer (score 16):

I couldn't get variations on `every three months` to work, either.

However, as a workaround I was able to set up four separate reminders each three months apart, since "every three months" falls on the same four dates every year:

```
/remind #random "yada yada..." every August 20th
/remind #random "yada yada..." every November 20th
/remind #random "yada yada..." every February 20th
/remind #random "yada yada..." every May 20th
```

Screenshot of result:
[image: Slack reminders every three months]

Answer (score -1):

this works for me as a reminder for every 1 day of every month

```
/remind @Someone "yala yala ..." every 1th
```